# Rails: pull value from has_many :through relationship in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-many-through

```
User   
  has_many :reservations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :events, :through => :reservations

Reservation
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event

Event
  has_many :reservations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :attendees, :through => :reservations, :source => :user
```

What I want is a method on `User` that I can query to find out the status of that user at a given event. Something like:

```
  def attendee_status(event)
    res = self.reservations.where(event: event.id).first
    if res
      res.status
    else
      0
    end
  end
```

I'm confused by the association syntax, among other things...`column reservations.event does not exist`

each user *should* only have one reservation for any particular event...`first` assumes that. (better way?)

anyway, the `status` method on `Reservation` model should return one of `%w[not_attending, awaiting_payment, payment_received]`

what's the "Rails way" to handle these relationship/look-ups from model to model (perhaps even starting with a clearer method name: `attendee_status(event)`)?!?

Answer (score 1):

`User.reservations` is a collection and `User.events` is a collection. Because your through association is linked via a `belongs_to` then both collections are the same size (assuming all reservations have an event).

`User.reservations.event` does not exist, but `User.reservations.first.event` will (assuming there is at least one reservation).

The first call is the function `Reservation::event` on the class, and the second is `Reservation#event` on an instance of the class. Calling `Reservation::first` on a collection gives you back an instance.

I think you just need to fix this line like so:

```
res = self.reservations.where(event_id: event.id)
```

I hope that helps.